# jquery tablesorter with condition

Tags: jquery, background, conditional-statements, tablesorter

I try to use tablesorter in jquery,if i click one column head, all the rows with the background color (e.g. red)on this column come all up,other fall behind. if i click another column head, all the rows, which on this column have red color background come up. I try to find a solution online, but no result. I wonder if it is possible. Thank you

[image]

```
function ParseExel() { 
this.parseExcel = function(file) {                                                                                  //构造函数，即读入的file file[0]
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        
        var data = e.target.result;
        var workBook = XLSX.read(data, {                                                                            //return Workbook object
            type: 'binary'
        });

        var jsonObj = new Array();
        var sheetCounter = 0;
        
        var jsObjLength;
        
        workBook.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            jsObj[sheetCounter] = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(workBook.Sheets[sheetName]);                 //read sheet out, get JS object
            
            // jsonObj[sheetCounter] = JSON.stringify(jsObj[sheetCounter]);                                         //conver to JSON object         ,not JS object
            //console.log(jsObj[3].NAMEINTERN)
            sheetCounter = sheetCounter + 1;
        })
            //console.log(jsonObj[1].length);
        jsObjLength = Object.keys(jsObj[0]).length;                                                                 //jsOjb length
        //console.log(length);
        // for (var index = 0; index < sheetCounter; index++) {
        //     $("#xlx_json_" + index).val(jsonObj[index]);
        // }
        
        var index=0;
        for (index = 0; index < jsObjLength; index++) {
            var name=jsObj[0][index].PROJEKT;

            if(name.startsWith("K")){   
               if(jsObj[0][index].TYP=='1'&&(jsObj[0][index].PROJEKT!==jsObj[0][index-1].PROJEKT)){                 //一个新项目 新 K, 新开1维
                    var pl=plChoose(jsObj[0][index].VERANTWRESSOURCE);
                    if(pl!==undefined){
                        var plLength=pl.length;
                        if(plLength==0){
                            pl[0]=new Array();
                            pl[0][0]=new Array();
                            pl[0][0].push(plBlock(index));
                        
                        }else{
                            var newLength_1Dim=plLength;
                            pl[newLength_1Dim]=new Array();
                            pl[newLength_1Dim][0]=new Array();                                                      //一个新的一维
                            pl[newLength_1Dim][0].push(plBlock(index));                                             //第一个 type 1
                        }
                    }
                              
               }else if((jsObj[0][index].TYP!=='1')&&(jsObj[0][index].PROJEKT==jsObj[0][index-1].PROJEKT)){         //还在旧项目里， type 不是 1， 而是2，3。这里只加2，3 Type
                    if(pl!==undefined){
                        var newLength_1Dim=pl.length;
                        var newLength_2Dim=pl[newLength_1Dim-1].length
                        var u=plBlock(index);
                        pl[newLength_1Dim-1][newLength_2Dim-1].push(u);                                             //不新开二维，在最后一个,即倒数第一个二维中继续加内容
                    }                        
               }
               else if(jsObj[0][index].TYP=='1'&&(jsObj[0][index].PROJEKT==jsObj[0][index-1].PROJEKT)){             //还在旧项目里,type =1, 新开2维
                    if(pl!==undefined){
                        var newLength_1Dim=pl.length;
                        var newLength_2Dim=pl[newLength_1Dim-1].length
                        pl[newLength_1Dim-1][newLength_2Dim]=new Array();                                           //一个新二维
                        var wert=plBlock(index)
                        pl[newLength_1Dim-1][newLength_2Dim].push(wert);                                                      
                    }
               }
            }
        }
    
      var allPl=new Array(
        data_R_03391,
        data_R_03344,
        data_R_03306,
        data_R_03205,
        data_R_03388,
        data_R_03343,
        data_R_03043,
        data_R_03292,
        data_R_03247,
        data_R_03345,
        data_R_02110,
        data_R_03362,
        data_R_02149,
        data_R_03441)
        //  $("#xlx_json_0").val(JSON.stringify(frontPattern));
        // $("#xlx_json_1").val(JSON.stringify(data_R_03391));
        var sortedArray=new Array();
        for (let index = 0; index < allPl.length; index++) {                                                            //index:pl
            loop1:
            for (let index1 = 0; index1 < allPl[index].length; index1++) {                                              //index1:K-Nummer
                loop2:
                    for (let index2 = 0; index2 < allPl[index][index1].length; index2++) {                             //index2:typ1
                        loop3:
                            for (let index3 = 0; index3 < allPl[index][index1][index2].length; index3++) {             //index3:typ 2,3 
                                var time=allPl[index][index1][index2][index3].Planende;
                                var status=allPl[index][index1][index2][index3].Status;
                                if(time!==undefined&&status!==undefined){                                               //type 1 没有Planende.

                                    if((dateoverdue(time)&&(status<'70'))||"40 50 60".includes(status)){
                                        sortedArray.push(allPl[index][index1][index2])                              //把符合条件的放入 sortedArray, [[1],[1],[1],,,]               
                                        break loop3;                                                                    //只要有一个满足，就不用再查后面的3维
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
            }
        }

        fillTableACondition(sortedArray);

        $(".tablesorter").tablesorter({
            background:"#ff7d7d"});//把表格变成sorttable
    
        // $("#xlx_json_0").val(JSON.stringify(frontPattern));
        // $("#xlx_json_1").val(JSON.stringify(data_R_03388[10][0]));
    };
```

Comment: Would you please [modify this demo with some mock data](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/) and how you're setting the background colors

Comment: Hallo, the colors are dynamically through Javascript (comparing dates) generated. the TRs and TDs are also generated from javascript through CreateElement...  Thanks

Comment: Ok, please add something into a demo so I can help troubleshoot

Comment: Hi Mottie, i put the code on it. actually only the last sentence is important. all others are only conditions and logic . the main function of the total programm is to read an excel file locally in front end. Backend is not a choice here.  I just no idea what condition i should put in  .tablesorter({???}). too many things. :)

Comment: @Mottie, you got any idea?